# OpenCOBOL can't find my external module to run the program

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to create a COBOL program using OpenCobol that has an external module when it does a calculation and then brings the result back into the main program using CALL. But everytime I try to run the program it says it can't find the module. I have already changed my module to Program Type "Module" from executable and I have added the module path as a Library path but nothing is working so far

Here is my main program code:

```
   PROGRAM-ID. Project2 AS "Project2".

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
  *****The student input file
       SELECT STUDENT-FILE-IN
           ASSIGN TO "C:\STUFILE.TXT"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

  *****The program input file
       SELECT PROGRAM-FILE-IN
           ASSIGN TO "C:\PROGRAM.TXT"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

  *****The student report output file
       SELECT STUDENT-REPORT-FILE-OUT
           ASSIGN TO "C:\REPORT.TXT"
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
  *Student input file
   FD STUDENT-FILE-IN.
   01 STUDENT-RECORD.
       05 STUDENT-NUMBER   PIC 9(6).
       05 TUITION-OWED-IN  PIC 9(4)V99.
       05 STUDENT-NAME-IN  PIC X(40).
       05 PROGRAM-OF-STUDY PIC X(5).
       05 COURSE-CODE-1    PIC X(7).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-1 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-CODE-2    PIC X(7).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-2 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-CODE-3    PIC X(7).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-3 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-CODE-4    PIC X(7).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-4 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-CODE-5    PIC X(7).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-5 PIC 9(3).

  *Program input file
   FD PROGRAM-FILE-IN.
   01 PROGRAM-RECORD-IN.
       05 PROGRAM-CODE-IN PIC X(5).
       05 PROGRAM-NAME-IN PIC X(20).

  *Student report output file
   FD STUDENT-REPORT-FILE-OUT.
   01 STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD-OUT PIC x(90).



   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  *Table to hold program records
   01 PROGRAM-RECORD.
       05 PROGRAM-TABLE.
           10 PROGRAM-CODE PIC X(5)  OCCURS 20 TIMES.
           10 PROGRAM-NAME PIC X(20) OCCURS 20 TIMES.

  *The student report record
   01 STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD.
       05 STUDENT-NAME     PIC X(40).
       05 FILLER           PIC X(2) VALUE SPACES.
       05 PROGRAM-NAME-OUT PIC X(20).
       05 FILLER           PIC X(4) VALUE SPACES.
       05 TUITION-OWED     PIC Z,ZZ9.99.

  *A line to make the output look good
   01 HEADER-LINE.
       05 FILLER PIC X(90) VALUE ALL "-".

  *The column header
   01 COLUMN-HEADER.
       05 NAME-COLUMN PIC X(42) VALUE "NAME".
       05 AVG-COLUMN  PIC X(7)  VALUE "AVE".
       05 PROG-COLUMN PIC X(24) VALUE "PROGRAM NAME".
       05 OWED-COLUMN PIC X(12) VALUE "TUITION OWED".

   01 CONTROL-FIELDS.
       05 STUFILE-EOF-FLAG  PIC A(3).
       05 PROG-EOF-FLAG     PIC A(3).
       05 PROG-SUB          PIC 9(2).
       05 FOUND-PROG-FLAG   PIC A(3).

   01 COUNTERS.
       05 STUDENT-RECORDS-READ-CTR    PIC 9(3).
       05 STUDENT-REPORTS-WRITTEN-CTR PIC 9(3).

   01 WW-SEND-AREA.
       05 STUDENT-AVERAGE  PIC 9(3).

   01 WW-SUB-PROG PIC X(75)
       VALUE 'C:\Users\google\Program3Call'.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   PERFORM 200-INITIALIZATION-RTN.
  *Read and process all student records
   PERFORM 200-PROCESS-STUDENT-RECORD-RTN
       UNTIL STUFILE-EOF-FLAG = "YES".
   PERFORM 200-FINISH-RTN.
   STOP RUN.

   200-INITIALIZATION-RTN.
       PERFORM 300-OPEN-FILES-RTN.
  *****Load all program records into the table
       PERFORM 300-LOAD-PROGRAM-TABLE-RTN
           VARYING PROG-SUB FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL PROG-SUB > 20 OR PROG-EOF-FLAG = "YES".
       PERFORM 300-INITIALIZE-REPORT-FILE-RTN.
       PERFORM 300-INITIALIZE-COUNTERS-RTN.

   200-PROCESS-STUDENT-RECORD-RTN.
       PERFORM 300-READ-STUDENT-RECORD-RTN.
       IF STUFILE-EOF-FLAG NOT EQUALS "YES"
  *********Get the program name
           PERFORM 300-GET-PROGRAM-NAME-RTN
               VARYING PROG-SUB FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL
               FOUND-PROG-FLAG = "YES" OR PROG-SUB > 20
           PERFORM 300-GET-STUDENT-AVERAGE
           PERFORM 300-PRINT-STUDENT-REPORT-RTN
       END-IF.

   200-FINISH-RTN.
       PERFORM 300-PRINT-COUNTERS-RTN.
       PERFORM 300-CLOSE-FILES-RTN.

   300-OPEN-FILES-RTN.
       OPEN INPUT STUDENT-FILE-IN.
       OPEN INPUT PROGRAM-FILE-IN.
       OPEN OUTPUT STUDENT-REPORT-FILE-OUT.

   300-LOAD-PROGRAM-TABLE-RTN.
       READ PROGRAM-FILE-IN
       AT END MOVE "YES" TO PROG-EOF-FLAG
       NOT AT END MOVE PROGRAM-CODE-IN TO PROGRAM-CODE (PROG-SUB)
                  MOVE PROGRAM-NAME-IN TO PROGRAM-NAME (PROG-SUB).

   300-INITIALIZE-REPORT-FILE-RTN.
       MOVE COLUMN-HEADER TO STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD-OUT.
       WRITE STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD-OUT.
       MOVE HEADER-LINE TO STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD-OUT.
       WRITE STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD-OUT.

   300-INITIALIZE-COUNTERS-RTN.
       MOVE 0 TO STUDENT-RECORDS-READ-CTR.
       MOVE 0 TO STUDENT-REPORTS-WRITTEN-CTR.

   300-READ-STUDENT-RECORD-RTN.
       READ STUDENT-FILE-IN
           AT END MOVE "YES" TO STUFILE-EOF-FLAG
           NOT AT END ADD 1 TO STUDENT-RECORDS-READ-CTR.

   300-GET-PROGRAM-NAME-RTN.
       IF PROGRAM-CODE (PROG-SUB) = PROGRAM-OF-STUDY
           MOVE PROGRAM-NAME (PROG-SUB) TO PROGRAM-NAME-OUT
           MOVE "YES" TO FOUND-PROG-FLAG
       END-IF.

   300-GET-STUDENT-AVERAGE.
        CALL WW-SUB-PROG USING WW-SEND-AREA.

   300-PRINT-STUDENT-REPORT-RTN.
       MOVE "NO" TO FOUND-PROG-FLAG.
       MOVE STUDENT-NAME-IN TO STUDENT-NAME.
       MOVE TUITION-OWED-IN TO TUITION-OWED.
       MOVE STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD TO STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD-OUT.
       WRITE STUDENT-REPORT-RECORD-OUT.
       ADD 1 TO STUDENT-REPORTS-WRITTEN-CTR.

   300-PRINT-COUNTERS-RTN.
       DISPLAY "Student records read: ", STUDENT-RECORDS-READ-CTR.
       DISPLAY "Student reports written: ",
           STUDENT-REPORTS-WRITTEN-CTR.

   300-CLOSE-FILES-RTN.
       CLOSE STUDENT-FILE-IN, PROGRAM-FILE-IN
           STUDENT-REPORT-FILE-OUT.


   END PROGRAM Project2.
```

Here is my Call Program:

```
  ******************************************************************
  * Author: Desiree Hanuman
  * Date: August 14th 2021
  * Purpose:Call Section code for project 3
  * Tectonics: cobc
  ******************************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. Program3Call.
   DATA DIVISION.
   LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 LS-STUDENT-AVERAGE-AREA.
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-1 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-2 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-3 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-4 PIC 9(3).
       05 COURSE-AVERAGE-5 PIC 9(3).
       05 STUDENT-AVERAGE  PIC 9(3).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE.
       100-STUDENT-AVERAGE.
             PERFORM 300-CALCULATE-AVERAGE-RTN.


       300-CALCULATE-AVERAGE-RTN.
       COMPUTE STUDENT-AVERAGE ROUNDED = (COURSE-AVERAGE-1 +
           COURSE-AVERAGE-2 + COURSE-AVERAGE-3 + COURSE-AVERAGE-4 +
           COURSE-AVERAGE-5) / 5.
   GOBACK.
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  Did you compile Program3Call as well as Project2?  Is your COBOL interpreted?  I'm wondering if you need to "link" the two programs to create an executable.

Comment: I am using OpenCobol. I compiled both of them and both are saying that the compilation is successful. How would I go about "linking" the two programs? All I have been seeing is just calling the other program in a routine. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You definitely should update to GnuCOBOL 3.1.2 instead of a very outdated OpenCOBOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to `CALL` in most COBOL implementations is to just specify the module name - without a path or extension.
Then you either do "static linking" (as in Scott's answer below for OpenCOBOL/GnuCOBOL just specify all sources on the command line and use either `-x` [fat executable] or `-b` [fat module, then callable for example with `cobcrun`], commonly with `-static`); or do "dynamic linking" (separate compilation of all modules) and specify the module path in a configuration file or by environment variable. For OpenCOBOL/GnuCOBOL this is `COB_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a user of OpenCobol, but, according to their manual in section 7, there are many ways to accomplish what you want.

But the simplest would be to statically compile and link the main and sub programs in one command line:

```
cobc -x Project2.cbl Program3Call.cbl
```

Comment: The link to the manual I referenced is https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/guides/OpenCOBOL%20Programmers%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This example work´s for me.

Please keep in mind that the name of the dll file routine module must be same as the routine name.

It is not necessary reconfigure OpenCobol path library.

I use OpenCobol 4.7.6.

The Code:

1. Main program (file build "MAINPROG.exe")

   ```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. "MAINPROG".
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

   DATA DIVISION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01  X PIC X(1).

   01  INPUTS.
       05 PRM-LENGTH PIC  S9(4) COMP.
       05 INPUT1     PIC   9(2).
       05 INPUT2     PIC   9(2).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   MAIN-PARA.
       MOVE 12 TO INPUT1.
       MOVE 13 TO INPUT2.
       CALL 'MFPROG1' USING  PRM-LENGTH, INPUT1, INPUT2.
       ACCEPT X.
       STOP RUN.

   END PROGRAM "MAINPROG".
   ```
2. Rutine program (file build module "MFPROG1.dll")

   ```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. "MFPROG1".
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   DATA DIVISION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01 OUTPUT-DATA    PIC  9(4).

   LINKAGE SECTION.

   01 PARM-BUFFER.
      05 PARM-LENGTH    PIC S9(4) COMP.
      05 PARM-INPUT1    PIC  9(2).
      05 PARM-INPUT2    PIC  9(2).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING PARM-BUFFER.

   MAIN-PARA.
       COMPUTE OUTPUT-DATA = PARM-INPUT1 + PARM-INPUT2.
       DISPLAY 'PARM-INPUT1: ' PARM-INPUT1.
       DISPLAY 'PARM-INPUT2: ' PARM-INPUT2.
       DISPLAY 'SUM VALUE  : ' OUTPUT-DATA.
       GOBACK.

   END PROGRAM "MFPROG1".
   ```